# Does jump measure of Brownian motion equals zero?

Tags: brownian-motion, random-measures

If $B=\{B_t\}_{t\ge{0}}$ is a Brownian motion adapted to $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\ge{0}},P)$, let's define a *Poisson random measure* (or *jump measure*) as follows:

> **Definition.** Let $\textbf{B}_0$ be the family of Borel sets $U\in{\mathbb{R}}$ whose closure $\bar{U}$ does not contain 0. For $U\in{\textbf{B}_0}$ we define the Poisson random measure as:$$N(t,U)=N(t,U,\omega)=\displaystyle\sum_{s:0<s\le{t}}{\chi_{U}(B_s-B_{s-})},$$
> where $\chi_U$ is the indicator funcion of $U$.

Since $N(t,U)$ counts the number of jumps of the Brownian motion whose size is in $U$ in the period $(0,t)$, and since the Brownian motion does an infinite number of jumps of intinitesimal size in every interval $(0,t)$, I'm trying to understand if $N(t,U)=\infty$ or $N(t,U)=0.$

**My attempt:** If I'm not wrong, a Brownian motion is a continuous process, so for all $t\ge{0}$ we have $B_t-B_{t-}=0$ a.s., but $0\notin{\bar{U}}$ which means that $N(t,U)=0$ a.s. for every $t\ge{0}$ and $U\in\mathbf{B_0}.$

Comment: Your attempt seems fine to me. Maybe just emphasize that $B_t - B_{t^-} = 0$ almost surely (some require trajectories to be always continuous, so that might not even be necessary). Scaled Brownian motions with drift are exactly those Levy processes which have zero jump measures.